# Validator getting access to delegator?

Tags: plutus, gougen

Is it possible for a validator to get access to delegator information? For example, is it possible to lock a token to be redeemable only by someone who is delegating to a specific stake pool?

Additionally, where can we find documentation about translating a staking address to a receive address off-chain, if we wanted to do airdrops manually until the Gougen release?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to determine wallet addresses from the staking address. There is currently no way to lock a token to be redeemable only by someone who is delegating to a specific stake pool. I assume this will be possible once smart contracts are live.

The simplest way to find other wallet addresses associated with a stake address is to look the address up on [Cardanoscan](https://cardanoscan.io/). [image]

If you want some details on how these addresses are derived, checkout Andrew Westberg's video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjPf_b9UQNs).